# Gitlab CE: можно ли создать кастомный title в URL merge request?

Tags: gitlab

После завершения пуша ветки git выдаёт URL для создания merge request. Выглядит он так:

```
/merge_requests/new?merge_request[source_branch]=BRANCH_NAME
```

По этому URL открывается форма, в которой нужно заполнить всякие поля.
Добавление `&merge_request[assignee_id]=ID` к этому URL (см. [Gitlab API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/api/merge_requests.html)) позволяет автоматически выставить нужное значение в селекте "Assign to". Но вот если добавить `&merge_request[title]=TITLE`, то свой заголовок не подхватывается. Можно ли как-то решить эту задачу?

P.S. В принципе можно сразу делать POST прямо в потроха гитлаба, как это описано в том же API. Но этап формы пропускать нельзя, она нужна. Хочется только подставить свой заголовок, по аналогии `с assignee_id`.

Comment: Почитал исходники, нашёл только выставление заголовка одноимённо тикету, который ветка закрывает, если ветка формата `номер_тикета-описание`. Скорее всего, стоит написать фич-реквест. Или таки создать через API и предложить поправить пост-фактум.

Comment: Не, второй вариант не подойдёт. Сделал пока костыль-подстановку через Tampermonkey...

Comment: Варианты "сделать на клиенте индивидуально" я даже не рассматривал, но если для вас это работает, почему нет :)

Comment: Так `assignee_id` всё равно на клиенте в URL подставляется, правда, проще - sed'ом по выводу `git push ...` :) Но, конечно, хотелось бы решить вопрос на другом уровне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение на клиентской стороне. Писалось для [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/)/Chromium, но вроде бы и для других браузеров сгодится. При открытии формы Merge Request заполняет поля "описание", "кто принимает" и "заголовок", если задано.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Gitlab Merge Request additions
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.5
// @description  Add title, labels, description & assignee_id to merge request
// @match        https://gitlab.*/merge_requests/new*
// @run-at       document-start
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    /* replace by own: */
    var ASSIGNEE_ID = "666";
    //var LABELS      = "фича";
    var DESCRIPTION = "Вставь описание, дундук!";

    /* based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486099/ code */
    function parse_query_string() {
        var query = location.search.substr(1);
        var result = {};
        query.split("&").forEach(function(part) {
            if(!part) return;
            part = decodeURIComponent(part.split("+").join(" "));
            var eq = part.indexOf("=");
            var key = eq>-1 ? part.substr(0,eq) : part;
            var val = eq>-1 ? part.substr(eq+1) : "";
            var from = key.indexOf("[");
            if(from==-1) result[decodeURIComponent(key)] = val;
            else {
                var to = key.indexOf("]");
                var index = decodeURIComponent(key.substring(from+1,to));
                key = decodeURIComponent(key.substring(0,from));
                if(!result[key]) result[key] = [];
                if(!index) result[key].push(val);
                else result[key][index] = val;
            }
        });
        return result;
    }

    var q = parse_query_string();
    if( !q.merge_request || !q.merge_request.source_branch )
        return;

    /* 
     * Как правильно внедриться в DOM тут не придумал, поэтому
     * делаем редирект при необходимости добавить assignee_id 
     * (потому и @run-at document-start)
     */ 
    if( typeof ASSIGNEE_ID != "undefined" && parseInt(ASSIGNEE_ID) 
        && !q.merge_request.assignee_id ) {
        var loc = Object.keys(q.merge_request).map( function(key) {
            return "merge_request[" + key + "]=" + q.merge_request[key];
        }).join("&") + "&merge_request[assignee_id]=" + ASSIGNEE_ID;
        document.location.search = loc;
        return;
    }

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        var e = document.getElementById("merge_request_title");
        if( e ) {
            /* title = BRANCH_NAME - 'empty placeholder' */
            e.value = q.merge_request.source_branch + " - ''";
        }

        if( typeof LABELS != "undefined" ) {
            /* id может быть и другим! */
            e = document.getElementById("s2id_autogen3");
            if( e ) e.value = LABELS;
        }

        if( typeof DESCRIPTION != "undefined" ) {
            e = document.getElementById("merge_request_description");
            if( e ) e.value = DESCRIPTION;
        }
    });

})();
```